# How to develop interface from C program with ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
I am trying to setup a interface between one c Program with ROS. IS there some helpful information?
The idea is that we run C program independent and use this interface send and receive information with ROS server to control PR2 simulator (ROS+Gazebo+PR2)
The framework is shown as following :
C program +interface with ROS +ROS +Gazebo+PR2.
Best regards.
Zhenli LU
Email. zhenli.lu@ua.pt

---

Update:

Dear DimitriProsser. Thank you very much for your email. In fact my C program does not expose any methods of communication. So Is there a C program client demo for ROS server. Thus I can use it for my project. In fact I am a new hand for ROS and PR2. I want to start from studying the interface with C program. Or how to develop the client program with C program to communicate with ROS server. Thus I can intergrate this client demo with my work in C program. Normally I use YARPmin.c and YARPmin.h as the interface to communcate with another middle ware YARP(Yet Another Robot Platform). Best regards. Zhenli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12811/how-to-develop-interface-from-c-program-with-ros/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably the best example of integration between a 3rd-party program and ROS is [Gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo). The situation depends on your external library though.

If your C program provides a communication API, you could write a ROS node that will interface with that API. Essentially, it would be a bridge between ROS and your C program. In this case, it would be very similar to writing a ROS driver for devices and very similar to Gazebo.

If your C program does not expose any methods of communication, you're going to have to modify the source code such that it does. For that, you can see [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/3277/wrap-existing-crrcsim-project-in-ros) question for some help.

**EDIT**:

You cannot include ROS's libraries in your C program because ROS is written in C++ and depends heavily on other C++ libraries (Boost, Eigen, etc.). What you need to do is expose the functions of your C program and wrap them in C++. This would allow you to use ROS with your application easily. Essentially, you would write a C++ application that instantiates and instance of your C application and collects and sends data via function calls.

Here is a quick, and very simplified example:

```
// My ROS application
#include "C_application_header.h"

class My_New_App
{
    My_New_App()
    {
        C_Application my_c_application;
        my_c_application->start();
    }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3